# Load image from Url without third-party

Tags: android, image, kotlin, url, data-binding

I'm trying to load image from URL with this code :

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
fun ImageView.bindImage(imgUrl: String?) {

    imgUrl?.let {
        val imgUri = imgUrl.toUri().buildUpon().scheme("https").build().toString()
        val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
        val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        var image: Bitmap?
        executor.execute {
            try {
                val `in` = URL(imgUri).openStream()
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(`in`)

                handler.post {
                    this.setImageBitmap(image)
                    executor.shutdown()
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("Tag", "onCreate: ${e.message}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the xml

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_album_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:imageUrl="@{albumsObject.albumImage}"
                android:src="@drawable/img_album_cover" />
```

it's worked fine .. but there's problems
1- when I run the emulator the laptop is heating up and the fan is getting very loud
2- if I scroll on the list of the recycler view the images binding slowly I can see the previous photo on the upcoming photo

Is there's a problem in this code ? or has any one have another way to load image from URL without using any third-party .. just Android SDK

Comment: `I can see the previous photo on the upcoming photo` Then use `setImageBitmap(null);` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this code:

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
fun ImageView.bindImage(imgUrl: String?) {

    if(this.drawable == null) {

        imgUrl?.let {
            val imgUri = imgUrl.toUri().buildUpon().scheme("https").build().toString()


            val uiHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
            thread(start = true) {
                val bitmap = downloadBitmap(imgUri)
                uiHandler.post {
                    this.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

fun downloadBitmap(imageUrl: String): Bitmap? {
    return try {
        val conn = URL(imageUrl).openConnection()
        conn.connect()
        val inputStream = conn.getInputStream()
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
        inputStream.close()
        bitmap
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(ContentValues.TAG, "Exception $e")
        null
    }
}
```

1. Check if it's not loaded yet to avoid more than one loaded.
2. Add HTTPS to the URL.
3. Create a thread to open an input stream connection and get the image bitmap.
4. Create a handler to return to main thread and set image bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
fun ImageView.loadImage(url: String?){
    val policy = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)
    val bitmap: Bitmap?
    val inputStream: InputStream
    try {
        inputStream = URL(url).openStream()
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return
    }
    this.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
}
```

Comment: Please dont use strictmode. Its bad coding and blocks. Use a thread.